# How can I add same item to cart but only increase quantity VueJS

Tags: vue.js

when I click at the same item, i would like add quantity on my Cart, but I create a new item on my cart :@ I push itemcart on list cart i think i must be add if/else on ?

my HTML:

```
<div class="bottom-0 right-0 fixed m-3 card bg-danger text-white">
        <span class="card-header">Panier</span>
        <div v-for="itemcart in listCart">
            <div class="card-body">
                <span>{{ itemcart.name }}</span>
                <span>{{ itemcart.price }}</span>
                <span>{{ itemcart.amount }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my data function:

```
data: function () {
        return {
            listCart: []
        }
    },
```

my methods on my component -> script:

```
methods: {
       
        addCart(product){
            const itemcart = {
                name : product.name,
                price : product.price,
                amount: product.amount

            };

            this.listCart.push(itemcart)
        }
    },
```

Comment: do you have a `product.id`? if so instead of an array use an object and use Object.values when you want it into an array, else your need use indexOf() or find() etc to find the item and increment it. your want a quantity prop too if updating else its just one product

Comment: nope :x i try this ty